# Get Iframe URL of envelope by which user can direct sign document

Tags: java, rest, docusignapi

I am new in Docusign.

I have a requirement to create an envelope and show envelope inside Iframe for adding the signature of the user. But I am not getting direct URL by that I user directly sign it.
Currently, the user is getting mail in that user is getting URL. On clicking on that URL, the user is able to sign.

I am using below code to generate URL for Iframe

```
public ViewUrl getViewUrl(EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary, Recipients recipients) throws ApiException{
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(DocusignFactory.appClient());
        RecipientViewRequest returnUrl = new RecipientViewRequest();
        returnUrl.setReturnUrl("https://www.docusign.com/devcenter");
        returnUrl.setAuthenticationMethod("email");
        Signer signer =  recipients.getSigners().get(0);
        returnUrl.setEmail("myemail@gamil.com");
        Tabs tabs = signer.getTabs();
        String usename= tabs.getFirstNameTabs().get(0).getName()+" "+tabs.getLastNameTabs().get(0).getName();
        returnUrl.setUserName(usename);

        return envelopesApi.createRecipientView(DocusignFactory.getDocusignLogin().getAccountId(), envelopeSummary.getEnvelopeId().toString(), returnUrl);}
```

By using above code I am getting URL. But that URL is just showing the envelope.

Getting Recipients object from EnvelopeTemplate Object and modifying object according to my inputs

```
public Recipients populateRecipients(Recipients recipients) {
        Signer signer =  recipients.getSigners().get(0);
        signer.setEmail("myemil@gmail.com");
        signer.setName("My Name");
        //signer.setNote("Here");
        signer.setRecipientId("1");
        signer.setClientUserId("1001");
        signer.setDeliveryMethod("Email");
        Tabs tabs = signer.getTabs();

        DateSigned dateSigned =  tabs.getDateSignedTabs().get(0);
        dateSigned.setValue("01/01/2017");
        dateSigned.setDocumentId("1");
        dateSigned.setRecipientId("1");
        //dateSigned.setTabId("1");
        List<DateSigned> dateSigneds = new ArrayList<DateSigned>();
        dateSigneds.add(dateSigned);
        tabs.setDateSignedTabs(dateSigneds);

        EmailAddress emailAddress =tabs.getEmailAddressTabs().get(0);
        emailAddress.setName("myemil@gmail.com");
        emailAddress.setDocumentId("");
        emailAddress.setRecipientId("1");
        //emailAddress.setTabId("2");
        List<EmailAddress> emailAddresss = new ArrayList<EmailAddress>();
        emailAddresss.add(emailAddress);
        tabs.setEmailAddressTabs(emailAddresss);

        FirstName firstName = tabs.getFirstNameTabs().get(0);
        firstName.setName("firstName");
        firstName.setDocumentId("1");
        firstName.setRecipientId("1");
        //firstName.setTabId("3");
        List<FirstName> firstNames = new ArrayList<FirstName>();
        firstNames.add(firstName);
        tabs.setFirstNameTabs(firstNames);

        LastName lastName = tabs.getLastNameTabs().get(0);
        lastName.setName("lastName");
        lastName.setDocumentId("1");
        lastName.setRecipientId("1");
        //lastName.setTabId("4");
        List<LastName> lastNames = new ArrayList<LastName>();
        lastNames.add(lastName);
        tabs.setLastNameTabs(lastNames);

        signer.setTabs(tabs);
        List<Signer> signers = new ArrayList<Signer>();
        signers.add(signer);
        recipients.setSigners(signers);
        return recipients;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one of the required parameters for the Recipient View (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) method --

clientUserId A sender created value that shows [that] the recipient is embedded (captive). Maximum of 100 characters.
Create a value for the clientUserId and include it for the signer when you create the transaction (when you send the signing request).

Then include it when you want the Recipient View. It's a security measure to ensure that it is ok for your web app to authenticate the signer.

Only include the clientUserId for signers where you can authenticate them yourself and you plan to offer them the embedded signing view.

Comment: when I am adding clientUserId, I am getting `UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT` message

Comment: Can you share the call how you are retrieving the recipientview?

Comment: I am using [link]https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client getting recipients object from EnvelopeTemplate object and modifying with my own inputs

Comment: Your call should like below: `{
 "authenticationMethod": "yourauthenticationmethod",
 "clientUserId": "recipientsclientuserid",
 "email": "recipientemail",
 "returnUrl": "yourappurl",
 "userName": "recipientname"
}`

Comment: In SDK, there is a test case https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java for this scenario, please check EmbeddedSigningTest() method.

Comment: I have implemented same. but getting above error. 
`{
  "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}`

Comment: This error normally comes when either envelopeId used is wrong or receipient details passed is wrong. Can you please check actual api data which is hitting DS platform, you can check API logs at https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: Yes, I have checked.

Comment: I dont know what was the problem in my test template. I have created new one and it is working now. Thanks.